# Custom KeyDown Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am very new to ASP.NET and this is my first job and I need to perfom good.

I am stuck on this search page where I have two text boxes. One searches by ID which is int, the second by last name. Both the searched populate a grid view. As per the requirement when the user types in last name and clicks search the grid view should populate which I got working. Now if the user stats typing in the ID Search text box the Lastname Search text box should clear as well as the grid view that had gotten populated should be hidden.

I achieved clearing the text box by using

```
txtSNumberSearch.Attributes["onKeyDown"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";

txtSNumberSearch.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').innerText='';", txtLastNameSearch.ClientID));

txtLastNameSearch.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').innerText='';", txtSNumberSearch.ClientID));
```

But am not able to clear or hide the grid view on key down in the text box, my boss says I need to create a custom key down event handler. I do not know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated as I really need to perform at this job.

Comment: Why do you have to do that on clientside? You could easily do that on serverside in the [TextChanged-Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx) of the Textboxes.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - It's more efficient since you don't need a server round-trip for each text change. Could use server-side if you need to hide it for security reasons and don't want it easily displayed again.

Comment: @keyboardP: If you need to perform the search, you have to to do the roundtrip anyway. After that you can also clear the other textbox.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - True, but that search would only require one round-trip. `TextChanged` would require a round-trip for each keypress.

Comment: @keyboardP: As i've understood the OP, the search will be triggered by the TextChanged-Event anyway. So theres no obvious advantage with using javascript.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - Ah, if that's the case, you're right and it would be easier to do it server side. I read it as the OP wants to simply hide the datagrid (old results) when the user types a new query, then show it again (with new results) after the user has pressed the search button. Think OP will have to clarify that.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way of hiding the `GridView` is by simply adding it into a standard `div` and hiding that.

```
<div id="divGV">
  <asp:GridView>...
</div>
```

You can hide the `div` by doing this in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("divGV").style.display='none';"
```

You've already got a handler added for `txtLastNameSearch`, so you could do something like this:

```
   txtLastNameSearch.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').value='';
document.getElementById("divGV").style.display='none';", txtSNumberSearch.ClientID));
```

Comment: You may want to consider using the .value property of the text box instead of innerText.

Comment: @Jay - Yes, I'll change it. I just copy/pasted his existing code which he says worked, but `Value` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Text boxes don't use InnerText. Try using value property. Keydown is just fine I think.

Try this.

```
txtSNumberSearch.Attributes["onKeyDown"] = "clearTextBox(this.id)";

txtSNumberSearch.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').value='';", txtLastNameSearch.ClientID));

txtLastNameSearch.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", string.Format("document.getElementById('{0}').value='';", txtSNumberSearch.ClientID));
```